# Php and Javascript connection

Tags: php, javascript

I'm very interested in if it is possible to connect javascript variables to php. I know that in php we can write javascript code, but on the contrary we could not. To express my aim better , lets bring example like that:

```
<form name="some" action="<?php $_SERVER['php_self']; ?>" method="post">
 <input type="submit" name="but" value="Action">
</form>
```

My question is how to make after pressing submit button to confirm (alert) with javascript and if it is confirmed do something (with php) and if isn't cancel (php operation).

Comment: You should be reading about AJAX...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things to pass javascript variable to php:

1. You can pass it as a hidden input field and submit it using POST

   `<input id="myHidden" name="myHidden" type="hidden"/>`

   Assign javascript variable to hidden input something like

   `var myVariable;`

   `document.getElementById("myHidden").value = myVariable;`
2. You can pass it as a query string with in your URL

As for confirming you can use javascript confirm, which will post on OK and not post/cancel on CANCEL

Something like:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?')"/>
```

Comment: Please bring some example with hidden input, I would be very pleasured :)

Comment: Thanks for helping, I never thought to do that like u offered lol :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="some" action="<?php $_SERVER['php_self']; ?>" method="POST"
 onsubmit="document.getElementById("response")
      = confirm('some question') ? 'yes' : 'no';
   return true;">
  <input type="hidden" name="response" id="response" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="but" value="Action">
</form>
```

BTW action="<?php $_SERVER['php_self']; ?>" opens up your page to XSS attacks.

Comment: that means that it is better to use in action="fileName.php" yes ? And also in this example what role has the hidden type, please give me some explanation :)

Comment: Yes, try it and see what gets posted